# Problem on multiplicative subsets 1

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $f:A\to{B}$ be a homomorphism of rings. If $f$ is surjective, is it true that every multiplicative subset $\Gamma\subseteq{B}$ has the form $f(\Sigma)$ with $\Sigma\subseteq{A}$ a subset multiplicative of $A$?

Please, I need help with this question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: $f^{-1}(Γ)$ is multiplicative.

Comment: $f^{-1}(Γ)$ is multiplicative because $f^{-1}(Γ)$ = $Σ$ which is multiplicative, not? But with this information what can I say about my exercise?

Comment: @rgl4 Let $a_1, a_2 ∈ f^{-1}(Γ)$. What can you say about $f(a_1·a_2)$?

Comment: I could say that $f(a_1 · a_2) \in Γ$ and then is multiplicative?

Comment: @rgl4 Well, yes. Exactly. Using the fact that $Γ$ is multiplicative:
$$f(a_1 ·a_2) = \underbrace{f(a_1)}_{∈ Γ} · \underbrace{f(a_2)}_{∈ Γ} ∈ Γ$$
Therefore, $a_1·a_2 ∈ f^{-1}(Γ)$. So $Σ = f^{-1} (Γ)$ is multiplicative and will do the job for $f(f^{-1}(Γ)) = Γ$ because of the surjectivity of $f$.

Comment: Ok, then I could say that in fact $Γ = f(Σ)$ and the question is true, not? A lot of thanks.

Comment: @rgl4 Yes, you could say that. The statement is true.